# Linux Server Has Free Memory, but Not Providing it To Tomcat Instance

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, memory

The following is the output of the free commmand on my Linux box:

```
    free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15043       7734       7309          0         66       2394
-/+ buffers/cache:       5273       9770
Swap:            0          0          0
```

As you can see there is about 7 Gig of free memory.  The other 7.8 gig is mostly being used by Tomcat.  However, I have started tomcat  with the following options:

```
-Xms13G -Xmx13G
```

So, I expect Tomcat to be given 13 gig of memory, but as you can see the total  used memory is only about 7 gig.  I'm out of ideas  as to how to how to force the  issue so that Tomcat instance is given 13 or at least 12 gig of memory.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me an explanation as to why this is happening or provides a solution.

Comment: you mean tomcat is given 13g but it is still not using it ?

Comment: Try connecting with JVisualVM and look at the max heap to see that indeed your java args were propagated to the TomCat java process.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi:  No, I mean tomcat is  given 7 Gig, sometimes it goes even up to 9 Gig.  The thing is that with -Xms13G -Xmx13G flags, the JVM is supposed to be given 13Gig right from startup; that the whole purpose of making these flags have the  same value.

Comment: @Amir Afghani:  Thanks for suggesting VisualVM. I connected it, and VisusualVM says that the  JVM indeed has 13Gig in terms of the heap.  It seems that Linux is at fault for reporting 7gig as being free.  It seems that Linux considers the part of the heap that is not being used as free, despite the fact that it has given it to the jvm.